# Indicate that a table's attribute is derived in SQL

Tags: sql, database, erd

Is there a way in SQL to specify that an attribute is derived? Currently, I'm creating a table `Employee`, which has a derived attribute `age`, but I've no idea how to indicate it (and I'm afraid there's no way to do it):

```
create table Employee(
    Id int NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Age int,  # How to indicate this is a derived attribute?
    Country varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    Birthrate double,
);
```

Comment: Do you mean how to indicate on ERD that `Age` is computed column or do you need code that will calculate `Age` based on SYSDATE and Birthdate?

Comment: Depending which ER you use you could use dotted border [ER Diagram Symbols and Meaning](https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/pages/chart/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning/ERD_attribute_symbols-497x125.PNG) and  https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ER-diagram-symbols-and-meaning

Comment: @lad2025 Actually, for now, I just need to write the SQL code. I thought there was a way in SQL to specify that an attribute must be derived, or something similar...

Comment: Do you use MySQL/Oracle/SQL Server?

Comment: @nbro How about trigger?

Comment: @lad2025 Regarding the Chen's notation for the ER-diagram, I was already aware of the fact that a dashed oval indicates a derived attribute, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Chuck Trigger is bad solution, will you update it every year? The better alternative is view or computed/generated column.

Comment: @lad2025 For now, I just need to write pure SQL code, so I'm not concerned with any particular database..

Comment: @nbro You need to know your DB because there is no such thing as pure SQL code. Every dialects handle it differently for example Postgresql has **[`Age()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)** function. Anyway SQL Server code **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/443866)**

Comment: The differences between the different implementations of SQL is especially apparent when it comes to dates and date functions.

Comment: I'm interested in the `Birthrate` attribute -- is this how quickly the Employee will have kids or how quickly the Employee was born?

Comment: @Hogan I think it's just a typo, it should be birthday or birthdate.

Comment: @nbro - this is an example of humor.

Answer (score 0):

If what You mean is that `age` is derived from `birthrate`, I think You should consider if You really need `age` column in Your table at all. If You are not creating data warehouse here, calculating age each time will be much saner than maintaining this column in production... Think of it - this column should be recalculated everytime someone have a birthday!

For convenience, You can always create view for it, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW Employee_view AS 
  SELECT 
    e.Id,
    =>here some database specyfic calculation to calculate age<= as Age,
    e.Country,
    e.City,
    e.Birthrate
 FROM Employee e;
```

Comment: I agree -- it is a really bad idea to put a calculated column in a table and not in a view.  You have have a process updating them every day if you put it in a column.  If someone fills out a form you can have a "age_reported" column.  I've seen this used a lot.